# IOS swift XML web service post method return null

Tags: ios, xml, soap

I am trying to execute SOAP service in IOS by SWIFT language. It returns null  don't know where i am making mistake, please guide me.

**my out put is**

```
access_token_ : b13a0cfe-1e42-43bf-a625-30c019f611a6
```

refresh_token : 221591ed-1248-4335-bddb-4ead6520ce7b

scope : read write trust

token_type : bearer

exe_url : https://elink.teknorapex.com:3636/xxxxxx/rest/IProcess/Get

Auth_companyId : 0000000000000010

Grnd_Acs_access_token_ : Bearer d5bc126d-5f6b-43ad-ae9c-b2ea7942a03b

<3c6f6175 74683e3c 6572726f 725f6465 73637269 7074696f 6e3e496e 76616c69 64206163 63657373 20746f6b 656e3a20 64356263 31323664 2d356636 622d3433 61642d61 6539632d 62326561 37393432 61303362 3c2f6572 726f725f 64657363 72697074 696f6e3e 3c657272 6f723e69 6e76616c 69645f74 6f6b656e 3c2f6572 726f723e 3c2f6f61 7574683e>

parse success!

nil

```
func get_Search_Process(refresh_token_ : String, mainELinkUrl : String) {



    let exe_url = "\(mainELinkUrl)IProcess/Get"



    let Auth_companyId = defaults.stringForKey("Auth_companyId")!

    let Grnd_Acs_access_token_ = "d5bc126d-5f6b-43ad-ae9c-b2ea7942a03b"//defaults.stringForKey("Grnd_Acs_access_token_")!



print("exe_url : \(exe_url)")

print("Auth_companyId : \(Auth_companyId)")

print("Grnd_Acs_access_token_ : Bearer \(Grnd_Acs_access_token_)")





Alamofire.request(.POST, exe_url,

    parameters: nil,

    encoding: .Custom({

        (convertible, params) in

        let mutableRequest = convertible.URLRequest.copy() as!                NSMutableURLRequest

        mutableRequest.HTTPBody = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><Get xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'><reqType>ADR</reqType><prjName></prjName><cusName>Teknor</cusName><folderName>5</folderName><submitterName></submitterName></Get>".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)



        return (mutableRequest, nil)}),

    headers:

    ["CompanyId": "\(Auth_companyId)" ,

        "Marketplace-ApiKey" : "8e77aa8059181079",

        "Authorization": "Bearer \(Grnd_Acs_access_token_)",

        "Accept" :       "text/xml",

        "Content-Type" : "application/xml; charset=UTF-8",

        "Accept-Charset" : "UTF-8",])

    .responsePropertyList { response in 

        //let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(response.data!)

        //print(xml)

        print(response.data!)

        self.parser = NSXMLParser(data: response.data!)



        let success:Bool = self.parser.parse()

        print(self.parser)

        if success {

            print("parse success!")

            print(response.result.value)

            print(self.strXMLData)



        } else {

            print("parse failure!")

        }

}

}



func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

    currentElement=elementName;

    /*if(elementName=="Project Name" || elementName=="CustomerName" || elementName=="Submitter Name" || elementName=="Request Number")

    {

        if(elementName=="Project Name"){

            passName=true;

        }

        passData=true;

    }*/

    print(elementName)

}



func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {

    /*currentElement="";

    if(elementName=="Project Name" || elementName=="CustomerName" || elementName=="Submitter Name" || elementName=="Request Number")

    {

        if(elementName=="Project Name"){

            passName=false;

        }

        passData=false;

    }*/

    print(elementName)

}



func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {

    strXMLData=strXMLData+"\n\n"+string

    print(strXMLData)

    if(passName){

        strXMLData=strXMLData+"\n\n"+string

    }



    if(passData)

    {

        print(string)

    }

    else{

        print("Not Found Char")

    }

}



func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: NSError) {

    NSLog("failure error: %@", parseError)

    print("failure error: %@", parseError)

}
```

Comment: Anyone can help me please, i am facing this problem for the past one week..,

Comment: now i found the issue because of NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)